# Attributes query; also include attributes with no hits on Inner join

Tags: mysql, attributes

I have an attributes system in which I can apply custom fields to products, like brand, size, etc... 
In the front-end of the site you'll see a list of products and a list of attributes to filter on and the number of items to expect:

- Brand A (12)
- Brand B (8)
- ...

Size:

- size a (9)
- size b (11)

After the filter I want to update the list of attributes and also include those records that have no 'hits'. With my current query I only get those records that have hits.

In short: how do I get the 0 items attributes?

I have this query (example with one attribute filter selected)

```
SELECT 
  attr.id, attr.title
  , attrval.value, attrval.id as valid
  , COUNT(attrlink.id) AS attrcount 
FROM #__foc_users_attributes AS attr 
LEFT JOIN #__foc_users_attr_val AS attrval 
       ON attrval.attrid = attr.id AND attrval.value !='' 
LEFT JOIN #__foc_users_attr_link AS attrlink 
       ON (attrlink.valueid = attrval.id) 
LEFT JOIN #__foc_users_items AS item 
       ON (item.id = attrlink.itemid) 
INNER JOIN #__foc_users_attr_link AS attrlink1 
       ON attrlink1.itemid = item.id 
      AND ((attrlink1.attrid=1 AND attrlink1.valueid=33)) 
WHERE item.published=1 AND attr.published = 1 AND attrval.value != '' 
GROUP BY attrval.id
```

Comment: Perhaps table schema can help. A solution may be write #__foc_users_items as first table and do left joins for all others, Why #__foc_users_attr_link has a inner join and not a left join?

Comment: You're right; I used a left join, for each different attribute group, and have it working now! Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  attr.id, attr.title
  , attrval.value, attrval.id as valid
  , COUNT(attrlink.id) AS attrcount 
FROM #__foc_users_attributes AS attr 
LEFT JOIN #__foc_users_attr_val AS attrval 
       ON attrval.attrid = attr.id AND attrval.value !='' 
LEFT JOIN #__foc_users_attr_link AS attrlink 
       ON (attrlink.valueid = attrval.id) 
LEFT JOIN #__foc_users_items AS item 
       ON (item.id = attrlink.itemid) 
LEFT JOIN #__foc_users_attr_link AS attrlink1   <<-- replace inner with LEFT join
       ON attrlink1.itemid = item.id 
      AND ((attrlink1.attrid=1 AND attrlink1.valueid=33)) 
WHERE item.published=1 AND attr.published = 1 AND attrval.value != '' 
GROUP BY attrval.id
```